# event.getHtmlLink() is returning NULL

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I'm building the application to insert the event in Google Calendar, but it's returning Null in event.getHtmlLink(). Which means it couldn't be able to insert Event. How to do that?

Insert Codes have been taken from:-
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert
and 
Actual quickstart Codes from:-
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

```
package com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear;

import android.Manifest;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventAttendee;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventReminder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AfterPermissionGranted;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;

/**
* MainActivity used for Google Api. It demonstrates how to use authorization to
*add event in Google Calender
* */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks{

    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICE = 1002;
    static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNT = 1003;

    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    GoogleAccountCredential googleAccountCredential;
    private static final String[] scopes = {CalendarScopes.CALENDAR};

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    /**
    * Create the main Activity.
    * @param savedInstanceState previously saved instance state
    * */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        Initialize credentials and service object
            googleAccountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(scopes)).
                    setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Calling Google Calendar API ...");


        sendResultToApi();

    }


    /**
     * Attempt to call the API, after verifying that all the preconditions are
     * satisfied. The preconditions are: Google Play Services installed, an
     * account was selected and the device currently has online access. If any
     * of the preconditions are not satisfied, the app will prompt the user as
     * appropriate.
     */

    private void sendResultToApi(){
        if(! isGooglePlayServiceAvailable()){
            acquireGooglePlayService();
        }
        else if (googleAccountCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null){
            chooseAccount();
        }
        else if (! isDeviceOnline()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Check Your Network Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            new MakeRequestTask(googleAccountCredential).execute();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date.
     * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
     *     date on this device; false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isGooglePlayServiceAvailable(){
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
    * Checks whether Device has Active Network Connection or not.
     * @return true if Network (Internet) is available ;
     * false otherwise
     */
    private boolean isDeviceOnline(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to resolve a missing, out-of-date, invalid or disabled Google
     * Play Services installation via a user dialog, if possible.
     */
    private void acquireGooglePlayService(){
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)){
            showGooglePlayServiceAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        }
    }
    /**
    *Display an Dialog showing Google Play Service is missing or Out of date
     * @paramConnectionStatusCode code describing the prescence or Lack :: Goggle Play service on Device
     */
    void showGooglePlayServiceAvailabilityErrorDialog(int connectionStatuscode){
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        Dialog dialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(MainActivity.this,connectionStatuscode,REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICE);
        dialog.show();

    }

    /**
    * Display currently LogIn Account on Device for selecting Account ,
    *so that CalendarId can be get For That Account..
     * Attempts to set the account used with the API credentials. If an account
     * name was previously saved it will use that one; otherwise an account
     * picker dialog will be shown to the user. The setting the
     * account to use with the credentials object requires the app to have the
     * GET_ACCOUNTS permission, which is requested here if it is not already
     * present. The AfterPermissionGranted annotation indicates that this
     * function will be rerun automatically whenever the GET_ACCOUNTS permission
     * is granted.
     *  */
    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNT)
    private void chooseAccount(){
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)){
            String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME,null);
            if (accountName != null){
                googleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                sendResultToApi();
            }
            else {
                //start a dialog so that user can select Acount Name
                startActivityForResult(googleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            }
        }else {
            // Request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission via a user dialog
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts).",
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNT,
                    Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);

        }

    }

    /**
     * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
     * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
     * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
     * @paramrequestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
     * @paramresultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
     *     activity result.
     * @paramdata Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
     *     activity result.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICE:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"This App Requires Google Play Service ! Please Install it and Try Again Later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    sendResultToApi();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                        data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName =
                            data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        SharedPreferences settings =
                                getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.apply();
                        googleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        sendResultToApi();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    sendResultToApi();
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    /**
     * Respond to requests for permissions at runtime for API 23 and above.
     * @param requestCode The request code passed in
     *     requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, String, int, String[])
     * @param permissions The requested permissions. Never null.
     * @param grantResults The grant results for the corresponding permissions
     *     which is either PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED. Never null.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(
                requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
   }
    /**---------methods implemented from EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks---------*/
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {
            //Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {
            //Do nothing
    }
    /**------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    /**
     * An asynchronous task that handles the Google Calendar API call.
     * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
     */

    private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;
        Event event;

        MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressDialog.hide();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Event Has been Successfully added  "+event.getHtmlLink(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            if (mLastError != null) {
                if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                    showGooglePlayServiceAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                            ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                            MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"The following error occurred:\n"+mLastError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Request Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            createEvent();
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * createEvent() method help in adding Event in google play service Calendar
        * */
        private void createEvent(){
             event = new Event()
                    .setSummary("There is Placement Drive")
                    .setLocation("Jalandhar")
                    .setDescription("Elite SmartCare Solutions is going to visit");
            DateTime date = new DateTime("2017-04-11T09:00:00-05:30");
            EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                    .setDateTime(date)
                    .setTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
            event.setStart(start);

            DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2017-04-12T09:00:00-05:30");
            EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                    .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                    .setTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
            event.setEnd(end);

            String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
            event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

            EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
                    new EventAttendee().setEmail("abc@nitj.ac.in"),
                    new EventAttendee().setEmail("xyz@gmail.com"),
            };
            event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

            EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                    new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
                    new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
            };
            Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                    .setUseDefault(false)
                    .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
            event.setReminders(reminders);

            String calendarId = "primary";
            try {
                event = mService.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

How to fix this code, so that one can insert Events in Google Calendar?

Update : 1
Logcat of Android Moniter

```
04-09 17:41:54.362 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-09 17:41:54.482 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: PartialUpdate status: Disabled
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Left Align: 0
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Width Align: 0
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Top Align: 0
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Height Align: 0
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Min ROI Width: 0
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Min ROI Height: 0
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Needs ROI Merge: 0
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Dynamic Fps: Enabled
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Min Panel fps: 45
04-09 17:41:54.542 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/qdutils: Max Panel fps: 60
04-09 17:41:54.682 3954-3968/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.777ms
04-09 17:41:56.732 3954-3968/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/art: Suspending all threads took: 51.622ms
04-09 17:41:56.892 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/Auth: [GoogleAuthUtil] GoogleAuthUtil
04-09 17:41:56.952 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:299)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.createEvent(MainActivity.java:363)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:320)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:272)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err: Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzat(Unknown Source)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzau(Unknown Source)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zzc(Unknown Source)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:269)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:294)
04-09 17:41:56.972 3954-4016/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear W/System.err:    ... 13 more
04-09 17:41:57.282 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
04-09 17:41:57.312 3954-4015/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear V/RenderScript: 0x55ab5f3610 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8
04-09 17:41:57.352 3954-3954/com.example.joshiyogesh.eventreminderbear I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3d3b858f time:55536505
```

Comment: It seems your Event object is never instantiated; you just declare it: Event event; When it is referenced, it will return null.

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: @BartW in createEvent() methods it's instantiating .

Comment: ah, sorry. I should have searched through the whole thing.

Comment: @Yohannes logcat has been uploaded

Comment: Have you found the issue yet? From the logs, it seems like its lacking some [authorization / permissions](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.19.1/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/UserRecoverableAuthIOException).

Comment: @SamuelKok couldn't be able to find, if you could help, it would be good.